# How to keep on updating a specific list within the for loop?

Tags: python

I'm very new to the world of programming, I've been trying to solve a specific python academic exercise but I ran into an obstacle.

The problem is that I need to generate a lucky numbers sequence, as in the user inputs a sequence [1,...,n] and these steps happen:

1. Every second element is removed
2. Every third element is removed
3. Every fourth element is removed
   .
   .
   .

When it becomes impossible to remove more numbers, the numbers left in the list are "lucky".

This is my code:

```
def lucky(l):
    index = 2
    new_list = []
    while(index<len(l)):

      for i in range(len(l)):
            if(i%index==0):
                new_list.append(l[i])
      index=index+1
    return new_list
```

The while loop is to have the final condition when " it is impossible to remove more numbers". However with every iteration, the list gets shorter more and more, but I don't know how to do it.

My code works for the first condition when index=2(remove every 2nd element), then in the following loops it doesn't work because:

- It is still limited by length of the original list.
- `new_list.append(l[i])` will just add more elements to the new_list, rather than updating it in its place.

I don't know how to update the list without creating multiple amounts of lists and with each iteration adding the new elements to a new list.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you keep removing every 2nd, 3rd, and 4th element, won't you eventually be left with only a single element? Just confused about the general process

Comment: With the three steps you gave, are they happening all to the original list, or one step at a time? Meaning do you want element 1, then element 5, then element 9 of the original list, or do you first want a list with only the even indexes (index starting at 0) then from that list remove every 3rd item, and then from that list remove every fourth item?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can remove items from your original list via `del l[index]`, where `index` is the index of the element to be removed.

For more details on lists look here:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

```
import math    

def lucky(l, index):
    for i in range(math.floor(len(l)/index)):
        del l[(i+1)*(index-1)]
```

Not sure if the code will work, as I cannot test it right now. But I think it should work somehow like that.

**EDIT:**

Tested it and the code works. If you want to run all three steps, just do:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

lucky(l,2)
lucky(l,3)
lucky(l,4)
print(l)
```

`>>>[1,3,7,13,15]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `del` with appropriate list slicing (see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) for more details) to update the list in-place:

```
def lucky(l):
    interval = 2
    while interval <= len(l):
        del l[interval-1::interval]
        interval += 1
```